# any insight into why activities that are in prod are missing in UAT?

Tags: sandbox-refresh

Activities are missing While refresh of full copy sandbox. It exist in production but missing in full copy sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce doesn’t delete archived activities, but you can manually delete them. When you create or refresh a sandbox, archived activities aren’t copied.

1. Criteria for Archiving Activities
   Salesforce archives certain year-old events and tasks every Saturday at approximately 5:00 AM Greenwich Mean Time (GMT).
2. Where Archived Activities Are Displayed
   After Salesforce archives activities, you can view them in exported data and in certain locations in Salesforce Classic. Activities are archived regardless of whether you use Salesforce Classic, Lightning Experience, or Salesforce1. However, although you can view archived activities in exported data and in Salesforce Classic, you can’t view them in Lightning Experience or Salesforce1.
3. Considerations for Archiving Activities
   Salesforce doesn’t delete archived activities, but you can manually delete them. When you create or refresh a sandbox, archived activities aren’t copied.

Please find more information here for your reference.

[Salesforce Helplink](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=activities_archived.htm&language=en_US&type=0)